# Insert a text with indentation persevered on the next line of matched string

Tags: yaml, language-agnostic

I have a file with a yaml data as below:

```
cat x.yml
foo:
 - bar: 1
 - zoo: 2
```

I am able to insert the text but this is messing the indentation(see 2nd line):

```
sed -r '/^[ ]+- bar:/a- hoo: 3' x.yml
foo:
 - bar: 1
- hoo: 3
 - zoo: 2
```

Then, I tried to backreference the leading spaces but seems like it is not working with `/a` flag.

```
sed -r '/^([ ]+)- bar:/a\1- hoo: 3' x.yml
foo:
 - bar: 1
1- hoo: 3
 - zoo: 2
```

Any help to get the following **using a one-liner** ?

```
foo:
 - bar: 1
 - hoo: 3
 - zoo: 2
```

Comment: You should YAML syntax aware parser like `yq` for this, can you install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to switch to GNU sed's `s` command:

```
sed -E 's/( *)- bar:.*/&\n\1- hoo: 3/' file
```

Output:

```
foo:
 - bar: 1
 - hoo: 3
 - zoo: 2
```

See: `man sed` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: @Kureteiyu: I can't follow that. When `bar` is `42`, it also works. I catch the space and number with `.*`.

Answer (score 3):

Best option is probably to use a parser. If you know exactly where the values should be, you can just pop them in there. Otherwise you'd have to loop and look for the "bar" key. This is using the [`YAML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML) module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML;

my $yaml = do { local $/; <> };
my $href = Load($yaml);
for (0 .. $#{ $href->{foo} }) {
    if (grep { $_ eq "bar" } keys %{ $href->{foo}[$_] }) {
        splice @{ $href->{foo} }, $_+1, 0, { hoo => 1 };
    }
}
print Dump $href;
```

It outputs:

```
foo:
  - bar: 1
  - hoo: 1
  - zoo: 2
```

Otherwise you can use Perl like so:

```
$ perl -pe's/^( *- *)bar.*\K/$1hoo: 1\n/s' x.yml
foo:
 - bar: 1
 - hoo: 1
 - zoo: 2
```

Capture from beginning of line `^` a dash surrounded by dashes. Expect "bar", then absorb everything after it into the regex match, including the newline at the end (hence the `/s` modifier). Keep (`\K`) everything that was matched, and after it, add on the captured dash-string, plus your new content and a newline. Done.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I agree with Inian saying a YML parser would be more appropriate here.

Nevertheless, you could use the `s` command and capture groups instead like

```
$ sed -r 's/^([ ]+)- bar:(.+)$/\1- bar:\2\n\1- hoo: 3/' x.yml
```

which gives

```
foo:
 - bar: 1
 - hoo: 3
 - zoo: 2
```